# DataDog metric automatically round to 2 decimal places

Tags: datadog

```
no code here
```

DataDog rounds of submitted metrics to 2 decimal places independent of unit provided with it or not.
For example if I submit metric point as `1107` or `1108` datadog will make it `1.18k` and then there is no way differentiate between them.

I tried with datadog v2 api with metric type(https://docs.datadoghq.com/metrics/units/) but no matter what I do it rounds off the value.

I need to display metric as table and not as query, is there any solution to prevent this auto round off OR to display last value correctly (as of now if I take last value, widget takes random row)